# Compile with Tramp hangs or fails when using Tramp with another command

Tags: tramp, compilation

I'm using Tramp with the scpx method to run the `compile` command on a remote machine.  The build takes several minutes to run.  If I try to work on something else while that runs that ends up trying to use Tramp, Emacs hangs and then the compilation buffer appears to abort the build.

For example, one time I started the compilation and then went to a dired buffer of the remote machine and tried to navigate, and that caused this to happen.

Another time, after starting the compilation, I tried to use `ido-find-file` on a remote path, and the compilation buffer failed.

I'm very new to Tramp and Emacs.  Should Tramp be able to handle multiple processes at the same time?  I wonder if I don't have something misconfigured.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Tramp is able to run several compile processes in parallel. It is the `compile` command which prevents this due to the hard-coded buffer name.

Check the docstring of `compile` by `C-h f compile`. There you see

> To run more than one compilation at once, start one then rename the
>   ‘*compilation*’ buffer to some other name with M-x rename-buffer. 
>   Then *switch buffers* and start the new compilation. It will create a
>   new ‘*compilation*’ buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Michael.  I guess I wasn't clear with my question.  I'm not trying to run `M-x compile` again.  I'm trying to do `ido-find-file` while the compilation buffer's process is still running.

Comment: I see. I've tried to reproduce your problem with a recent Emacs 25.1 / Tramp 2.3.0-pre, but everything works as expected. Which Emacs / Tramp versions are you using?

Comment: I'm using Emacs 24.5.1, with Tramp 2.2.11-24.5.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it with GNU Emacs 24.5.1 / Tramp 2.2.11-24.5, as brought by Ubuntu 15.10. I've used your scenario, calling `M-x compile` on a remote host, and calling `M-x ido-find-file` while the compilation was still running. No problem. The only difference might be that I have started Emacs as `emacs24 -Q`. Have you tried it yourself, starting Emacs with the -Q option?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but you are right, my problem goes away when I use `emacs -Q`.  So does that mean that something in my `init.el` is causing an issue?

Comment: Yes. Try bisecting your `init.el`, in order to find the responsible code.

Comment: I think there were at least a two things going on.  First, I was using [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl), which would call Mercurial on the remote machine when I opened a file, and it would hang.  Adding "HGPLAIN=1" to  `tramp-remote-process-environment` fixes that, and I can now navigate a `dired` buffer and open files while compilation continues.  But I still can't use `ido-find-file`.  I think [ido-ubiquitous](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous) might be causing the issue.  Disabling it fixes things.  Thanks so much for the help, Michael!

Comment: I re-enabled `ido-ubiquitous-mode`, and things still worked, so maybe that isn't related after all.  I occasionally do still get Emacs to hang when I try to use `ido-find-file`, and then I have to hit `C-g` and try again, and it eventually works just fine.  So some issue is still lurking.  But for the most part, things are working nicely.